# How do you open the VBA editor in MS Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How do I get to the VBA editor in MS Word 2013? All my searches return information on Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to enable the Developer button in Word.

Click `File`, then `Options`, `Customize Ribbon`.

Then Select the `Developer` tab checkbox.

`Developer` will appear is a menu option now.  Select it and you can the select `Visual Basic` to open the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Visual Basic Dev Button]

I think you can access it via the visual basic button under the Developer tab as above