# MS Word - Scroll document at the middle of the page?

Tags: microsoft-word, cursor, text-cursor

It would be fantastic if MS Word allowed us to automatically start scrolling the document at the middle of the page, so we don't have  to move our eyes  from top top till the end of the screen (vertical movement).
Let's assume that we are a page ahead (`CTRL/ALT + Intro`, does the trick), so we already created a new page which is below the current one; that way the processor doesn't have to get to the bottom to create a new blank page which allows us to keep typing.
Is it possible to do that?
To make my question more explanatory, I took some time to make this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIaQCvRpFpI&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open VBA Editor ([How do you open the VBA editor in MS Word](https://superuser.com/questions/745117/how-do-you-open-the-vba-editor-in-ms-word-2013));
2. Edit the file code "ThisDocument" of project "Notmal"
   ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGvKD.png));
3. Paste it:

```vbnet
Option Explicit

Sub AddKeyBinding()
    With Application
        .CustomizationContext = ThisDocument
        .KeyBindings.Add _
            KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyReturn), _
            KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
            Command:="EnterScroll"
    End With
End Sub

Sub EnterScroll()
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=2
    Selection.TypeParagraph
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
    AddKeyBinding
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    AddKeyBinding
End Sub
```

4. Reopen Word.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, turns out that the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + S` allows the user to split the page, which is pretty useful to see to different sections of the same document. And is also very useful to type while the document cursor stays in the middle of the page if split correctly.